# asana api fail to add project to task after add followers (I use asana-api-php-class)

Tags: php, asana-api

I add project to this task after create task "without" followers.
 And it works.

But when I add project to this task after create task "with" followers.
 And it dose not works.

I use below php library.

https://github.com/ajimix/asana-api-php-class

thank your answer.

PS: I have try to sleep 1 or 2 seconds, and still not working.

Comment: Have you tried using the official Asana php library?
https://github.com/Asana/php-asana

Comment: thx u, I found that yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if the user used to create that task isn't added as a follower, then this will fail. The API must add the user who created the task as follower by default and when you provide the followers, that is getting overridden.